# Render child records into specific outlet

Tags: ember.js

I have this working example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bazzel/SM5VM/) where I'm showing a list of **Posts**. When a **Post** is selected, I display the details in the outlet of the posts template. No problem so far.

Since every **Post** *has many* **Comments** and *has many* **Trackbacks**, I'd like to have the **post/show** template to show two tabs, so I can show either the comments or the trackbacks beneath the details.

For this the post/show template looks like this:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="post/show">
    <h3>{{controllers.post.title}}</h3>
    <p>{{controllers.post.description}}</p>
    <hr/>
    <ul>
        {{#linkTo comments tagName="li"}}<a {{bindAttr href="view.href"}}>Comments</a>{{/linkTo}}
        {{#linkTo trackbacks tagName="li"}}<a {{bindAttr href="view.href"}}>Trackbacks</a>{{/linkTo}}
    </ul>
    {{outlet}}
</script>
```

The comments and trackbacks routes are basically identical:

```
App.CommentsRoute = Em.Route.extend({
    setupController: function (controller, model) {
        comments = this.controllerFor('post').get('comments');
        controller.set('content', comments);
    },
    renderTemplate: function () {
        this.render({
            into: 'post/show'
        });
    }
});
```

My question is about **renderTemplate**: I would like to render the **comments** template into to **outlet** of the **post/show** template, but this is not working. When I replace the **into** value with another existing template (e.g. **application**, **posts**, **post**) I do see the **comments** appear.

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One great way to help debugging router issues is to turn on the router logging:

```
window.App = Em.Application.create({
    LOG_TRANSITIONS: true
});
```

This lets you see which route you are transitioning into.  In your case, when navigating to the comments section it shows:

```
Transitioned into 'posts.index'
Transitioned into 'posts.post.show'
Transitioned into 'posts.post.comments'
```

This means that your `post.show` route is not active when you transition to the `comments` route, which is why you can't render into its `{{outlet}}`.

Since you are not using the `post` template for any actual content you can rename your `post/show` template to `post` and get rid of the `show` route.  This makes sure that template is still around when you want to insert the `comment` or `trackback` template.

```
App.Router.map(function () {
    this.resource('posts', function () {
        this.resource('post', {
            'path': '/:post_id'
        }, function () {
            this.resource('comments');
            this.resource('trackbacks');
        });
    });
});
```

Since you changed the template from `post/show` to `post` the `postController` will contain the post passed from `posts`, so you can drop the `controllers.post` and access the properties of the post directly:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="post">
...
<h3>{{title}}</h3>
<p>{{description}}</p>
....
</script>
```

Now all you have to do is update the targeted route to render into, which is now just `post`:

```
renderTemplate: function () {
    this.render({
        into: 'post'
    });
}
```

[Working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SM5VM/21/)

**Update**

You can have the `show` route render into `posts` route which will replace the `post` template with your `post/edit` template:

[Updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SM5VM/25/)

```
App.Router.map(function () {
    this.resource('posts', function () {
        this.resource('post', {
            'path': '/:post_id'
        }, function () {
            this.route('edit');
            this.resource('comments');
            this.resource('trackbacks');
        });
    });
});

App.PostEditRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    renderTemplate: function() {
        this.render({into: 'posts'});   
    }
});
```

Comment: The example was an extract from a bigger piece of code in which I also have an `edit` route next to the `show` route, so I thought I actually need the `post` resource and her `show` route. How would the solution look like if I do not want to get rid of the `show` route? RyanJM's answer works but I don't understand why I need `this.render` twice?

Comment: I updated the example to include a `post.edit` route, but it still doesn't use the `show` route.

Comment: Excellent! Not using a seperate `show` solved my problem. Now I can also remove the `renderTemplate` from my `CommentsRoute` and `TrackBacksRoute` since they're automatically rendered into `post`.  My [update JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bazzel/SM5VM/27/). Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It is a little strange, but you have to tell the route to render the `post/show` again.

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ryanjm/bfXUJ/1/).

```
renderTemplate: function () {
    this.render('post/show');
    this.render({
        into: 'post/show'
    });
}
```

---

**Update:** fixed the link

Answer (score 0):

If you want to render the template into a different named outlet

```
App.PostsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  renderTemplate: function() {
    this.render({ outlet: 'posts' });
  }
});
```

Reference: [Ember Documentation](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/rendering-a-template/)