# Ember #linkTo displays blank area when navigating back from editing record

Tags: ember.js

This is a follow up to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15146630/render-child-records-into-specific-outlet).

[Working JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/bazzel/uCggc/).

My `Router` basically looks as follows:

```
App.Router.map(function () {
    this.resource('posts', function () {
        this.resource('post', {
            'path': '/:post_id'
        }, function () {
            this.route('edit');
            this.resource('comments');
            this.resource('trackbacks');
        });
    });
});
```

Since I want both my `post` and `post/edit` template to be rendered into the same `{{outlet}}`, I've overridden the `PostEditRoute` for this (hence the `renderTemplate` which takes care of this). I need to override `model` as well to use the `PostRoute`'s model:

```
App.PostEditRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return this.modelFor('post');
    },
    deactivate: function() {
        this.currentModel.get('transaction').rollback();
    },
    renderTemplate: function() {
        this.render({
            into: 'posts'
        });   
    }
});
```

My `post/edit` template contains a **Cancel** link that I want to 'redirect' back to the `post` view.

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="post/edit">
    {{view Em.TextField valueBinding="title"}}
    {{view Em.TextArea valueBinding="description"}}
    {{#linkTo post}}Cancel{{/linkTo}}
</script>
```

But this is where the trouble starts: clicking the **Cancel** link will show a blank area i.o. the `post` template.

I also tried a pass a param to the `#linkTo` helper (`#linkTo post this`); that does show the `post` template, but results in a `Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded` error when going back to `post/edit`.

My question: how can I navigate back to `post` when cancelling to `post/edit`?

Answer (score 0):

I found it best to always nest my resources and routes only if their UI is nested.

Nesting `edit` under `post` when their UI isn't nested will make you fight against Ember, which will cause you problems and not allow you to take advantage of conventions.

Since `edit` view is nested inside `posts`, why not nest `edit` in `posts`.

```
this.resource('posts', { path: '/' }, function () {
  this.route('edit', { path: '/post/:post_id/edit'});
  this.resource('post', {
    'path': '/:post_id'
  }, function () {
    this.resource('comments');
    this.resource('trackbacks');
  });
});
```

When I updated the routes, I was able to remove a lot of boilerplate code.

Here's the working Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/teddyzeenny/uCggc/2/

Note: The `Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded` is happening because you are passing `this`, which is the entire controller, to the `linkTo` helper instead of just the model (`content`).

This was fixed in Ember master, so until you update to the latest build, use `{{#linkTo posts.edit content}}`

Comment: That works indeed. However, I would prefer to define `edit` as a route for `post`, since I'm modifying a single object. I haven't tested it against master though.

Answer (score 0):

Define your model and router mapping as follows:

```
App.Post = DS.Model.extend({
    text: DS.attr('string'),
});

App.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('posts');
    this.resource('post', { path: '/post/:post_id' }, function() {
       this.route('edit'); 
    });
});
```

Since you supplied a function to the `resource` call for `post`, Ember automatically redirects `/post/:post_id` to the route `App.PostIndexRoute`, with template `post/index` (more on this in [the official guide](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/defining-your-routes/#toc_resources). Let's put the 'show' formatting here.

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="post/index">
    <h1>Post '{{content.id}}'</h1>
    <p>text: {{content.text}}</p>    
    <p>{{#linkTo 'post.edit' content}}Edit{{/linkTo}}</p>
    <p>{{#linkTo 'posts'}}Back to index{{/linkTo}}</p>
</script>
```

Now we have the `post/edit` template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="post/edit">
    <h1>Editing post '{{content.id}}'</h1>
    <label>Text:</label><br/>
    {{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="content.text"}}<br/>
    {{#if content.isDirty}}
        <em>Modified.</em><br/>
    {{/if}}
    <button {{action submit}}>Submit</button>
    <button {{action cancel}}>Cancel</button>
</script>
```

The `post` template is nothing more than an outlet.

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="post">
    {{outlet}}
</script>
```

Finally, we need to handle the `submit` and `cancel` actions in `PostEditController`.

```
App.PostEditController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    content: null,
    submit: function() {
        var post = this.get('content');
        post.get('transaction').commit();
        this.transitionToRoute('post', post);
    },
    cancel: function() {
        var post = this.get('content');
        post.get('transaction').rollback();
        this.transitionToRoute('post', post);
    },
});
```

Here's the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ahmacleod/ghcR7/).